# Polish TextToSpeech in Xamarin - Android

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, text-to-speech

I am writing an application for Android with Xamarin and I need to implement text-to-speech in Polish language.

My first step was, of course, to google it and I've found out that text-to-speech is implemented already in Xamarin ([link to developer.xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech/)).

Unfortunatelly, not in Polish (there is a way to change language, but I wasn't able to change it to Polish). Is there a way to do this?

I've found a nice website with text-to-speech in many languages and free non-commercial api: https://responsivevoice.org/api/

But, it works in JS and I don't know a way to implement JS in Xamarin, Android app. Is there a way to do this?

There are some other free text-to-speech APIs, but they don't seem to sound great, just 3/10 or something, but my work is an engineer project, so I don't wont to use such weak things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports Polish and a couple of dozen other languages, you could do this in the (`TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener`) `OnInit` method to review all the languages available and set the one you want:

```
public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
{
    if (status.Equals(OperationResult.Success))
    {
        foreach (var locale in speaker.AvailableLanguages)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, locale.Language); // review all the languages available
            if (locale.Language == "pl")
                speaker.SetLanguage(locale);
        }
        speaker.Speak("jak się masz?", QueueMode.Flush, null, null);
    }
    else
        Log.Error(TAG, status.ToString());
}
```

iOS also supports a couple of dozen languages, including Polish (`pl-PL`). You can review all the support languages via `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.GetSpeechVoices()` and assign one via the `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.FromLanguage` to the `AVSpeechUtterance.Voice` property:

```
foreach (var voice in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.GetSpeechVoices())
{
    Console.WriteLine(voice.Language); // review all the languages available
}
var speechSynthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();
var speechUtterance = new AVSpeechUtterance("jak się masz?")
{
    Voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.FromLanguage("pl-PL"),
    Volume = 1.0f,
    PitchMultiplier = 1.0f
};
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for anwser. I implemented it and still it doesnt speak in polish. I track avaliabvle languages in debugger at tts, there is the list:
  Language "en"
  Language "de"
  Language "fr"
  Language "es"
  Language "de"
  Language "it"
  Language "it"
  Language "en"
  Language "es"
  Language "fr".. So what is the reason that polish is missing? Is it connected with fact, that my VS is in english or what?

Comment: @snilmerg Would not have anything to due with Visual Studio, it would be the actual device/phone.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Emulator for Android, because it is more responsive than VS build-in one. I changed language at device to polish, before tts was working in english, now it isnt at all

Comment: @snilmerg I know that **Google's** Android emulators (AVD) come configured with all the languages, I do not know if the Microsoft Hyper-V based ones do(?).